# WIFI P2P stops discovering peers and doesn't accept connections after 2 minutes

Tags: android, wifi, p2p, wifi-direct

I have been messing around with the following issue for about 2 months now.

I am building an application on a custom android board which will act as a wifi display (WFD). When I boot the board, I can easily connect from several different phones (LG Optimus G, LG Optimus G pro, Samsung S3 and S4). After connecting and watching the screen being duplicated on the TV screen attached to the custom board, I can then disconnect and if I reconnect within 2 minutes, I can connect again.

If I boot the board (or disconnect) and then wait 2 minutes, the device no longer sees the phones, and the phones sometimes sees the board, and sometimes not. If the phone sees the board, I can initiate a connect, but I cannot connect succesfully.

I have tried all kind of options, but none seem viable.

The board is running on AOSP 4.2.2

I have right now some complicated code that does restart the discoverPeers function every 40 seconds, as normally it stops after 30 seconds. Besides that I disable WFD and re-enable it, with a 4 second delay between it.

I also tried disabling and reenabling p2p and the channel, all with no result.

Below is my code, the receiver is in a separate class.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER);
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
    setContentView(R.layout.wifi_direct_discovery);
    connectPicture = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    isConnecting = false;
    localWifiP2pWfdInfo = new WifiP2pWfdInfo();

    localWifiP2pWfdInfo.setWfdEnabled(true);
    localWifiP2pWfdInfo.setDeviceType(1);
    localWifiP2pWfdInfo.setSessionAvailable(true);
    localWifiP2pWfdInfo.setControlPort(7236);
    localWifiP2pWfdInfo.setMaxThroughput(50);
    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

    @Override
public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers)
{
    List<WifiP2pDevice> peersList = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deviceListView);

    peersList.clear();
    peersList.addAll(peers.getDeviceList());

    if (peersList.size() == 0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "No devices found");
        list.clear();
        if ((pd != null) && pd.isShowing() && (isConnecting == false))
        {
            pd.dismiss();
            Log.d(TAG, "Closed connecting dialog, restarting P2P");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connection failed please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            restartP2p(false);
        }
        else if (isConnecting == false)
        {
            restartP2p(false);
        }
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_black_text, R.id.list_content, list));
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        for (i = 0; i < peersList.size(); i++)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Found device: " + peersList.get(i).toString());
            list.add(peersList.get(i).deviceName);
            if ((pd != null) && pd.isShowing())
            {
                if (peersList.get(i).deviceAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(client.deviceAddress))
                {

                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            if ((pd != null) && pd.isShowing())
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to find current client: closed connecting dialog, restarting P2P");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                restartP2p(false);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to find current client, but we weren't trying to connect");

            }
        }
    }
    listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_black_text, R.id.list_content, list));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo p2pInfo)
{
    if (p2pInfo.isGroupOwner)
    {
        stopP2PDispeerTimeoutThread();
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected as group owner");
        int i = p2pInfo.mWfdRtspPort;
        Log.d(TAG, "------------------------- onConnectionInfoAvailable rtsp port = " + i);

        // get the ip addres from the connected client. Mac address is in
        // client

        String sourceIP = null;
        while (sourceIP == null)
        {
            sourceIP = getIPFromMac(client.deviceAddress);
            millisleep(250);
            if (sourceIP == null)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get client address!!!!! from " + client.deviceAddress);
            }
        }
        if (i == 0)
        {
            // this is not a wfd source, so let's get into client mode for
            // upgrade etc.
            Log.e(TAG, "This device is not a WFD source, so switch to client mode, device = "
                    + client.deviceAddress);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Start connect to source : " + sourceIP);
            if ((pd != null) && pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
            // need to stop the connection timeout thread here..
            stopConnectTimeoutThread();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WFDPlayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SOURCE_IP", sourceIP);
            intent.putExtra("RTSPPORT", i);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 210);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connected as peer, this is very very wrong!!!!, restartP2P");
        restartP2p(false);
        startP2PDispeerTimeoutThread(34);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionRequested(WifiP2pDevice arg0, WifiP2pConfig arg1)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "------------------------------------- onConnectionRequested");
    stopP2PDispeerTimeoutThread();

    isConnecting = true;
    client = arg0;
    if ((pd != null) && (pd.isShowing()))
    {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
    if (client != null)
    {
        createConnectionProgressDialog(client.deviceName);
    }
}

public void onResume()
{
    if (first_time == false)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");

        intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED");
        intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED");
            intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE");
        intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED");
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
        if (!mP2PDispeerThread.isRunning)
            startP2PDispeerTimeoutThread(34);
        manager.setDialogListener(channel, this);
        manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "discoverPeers success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "discoverPeers failed");
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume, first time");
        restartP2p(first_time);
        first_time = false;
    }
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    super.onResume();
}


public void restartP2p(boolean first)
{
    if (first)
    {
        mWifiManager = ((WifiManager) getSystemService("wifi"));
        mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        sleep(4); // was 4
        manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        manager.enableP2p(channel);
        sleep(3); // was 3
        mDisplayManager = ((DisplayManager) getSystemService("display"));
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mlock = mWifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF , "LockTag");
        mlock.acquire();
        instance = this;

        receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

        manager.setWFDInfo(channel, localWifiP2pWfdInfo, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
        {
            public void onFailure(int paramAnonymousInt)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to set WFD info with reason " + paramAnonymousInt + ".");
            }

            public void onSuccess()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "updateWfdEnableState");
            }
        });
        sleep(1);
        manager.setDialogListener(channel, this);
        manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "discoverPeers success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "discoverPeers failed");
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        manager.stopPeerDiscovery(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "stopPeerDiscovery success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "stopPeerDiscovery failed");
            }
        });

        localWifiP2pWfdInfo.setWfdEnabled(false);
        manager.setWFDInfo(channel, localWifiP2pWfdInfo, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
        {
            public void onFailure(int paramAnonymousInt)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to set WFD info with reason " + paramAnonymousInt + ".");
            }

            public void onSuccess()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "updateWfdEnableState");
            }
        });
        sleep(4);
        localWifiP2pWfdInfo.setWfdEnabled(true);
        manager.setWFDInfo(channel, localWifiP2pWfdInfo, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
        {
            public void onFailure(int paramAnonymousInt)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to set WFD info with reason " + paramAnonymousInt + ".");
            }

            public void onSuccess()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "updateWfdEnableState");
            }
        });

        manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "discoverPeers success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "discoverPeers failed");
            }
        });
    }

    if (first)
        startP2PDispeerTimeoutThread(40); // only start the thread 1 time...
}
```

In the logging initially I see that the device and the phone connect successfully. 
After disconnect, I see the devices being lost in the log, and after that, when I try to connect, I see the message:
               I/wpa_supplicant(1839): [CTRL_IFACE]p2p0: P2P_CONNECT da:57:ef:cb:8e:be pbc go_intent=0

After this everything stops, the application is still running, I could see that from a log line that runs every second in the thread that stops and restarts the discovery every 40 seconds.

If anyone has any idea left why this behavior is happening, let me know. The only way to recover right now is to reboot the board (but that is not an option).

Thanks for your replies,
Arvy

Comment: Solved this issue by restarting the wifi stack every 2 minutes..